# I'm trying to push my python code to Heroku but the push fails every time

Tags: python, heroku

I used the command `git push heroku master` and this is the output error:
I think it is a problem with PostgreSQL. I believe that the installation of psycog2 is what is stopping the push, but I am unsure of how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix it, I already tried fixing it by changing the requirements.txt

```
`Enumerating objects: 43, done.
 Counting objects: 100% (43/43), done.
 Delta compression using up to 2 threads
 Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 1.53 MiB | 1.41 MiB/s, done.
 Total 43 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
 remote: Compressing source files... done.
 remote: Building source:
 remote: 
 remote: -----> Python app detected
 remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.3
 remote: -----> Installing pip
 remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
 remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
 remote:        Collecting Flask==0.10.1
 remote:          Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544 kB)
 remote:        Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
 remote:          Downloading Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.1.tar.gz (95 kB)
 remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.4.5
 remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
 remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==0.24
 remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46 kB)
 remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.8
 remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263 kB)
 remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23
 remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz (13 kB)
 remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1
 remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371 kB)
 remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;                     sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/pip-egg-info
 remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/
 remote:            Complete output (7 lines):
 remote:            running egg_info
 remote:            creating /tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
 remote:            writing /tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-     INFO
 remote:            writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/pip-egg-     info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
 remote:            writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/pip-egg-     info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
 remote:            writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-4i9g6x68/psycopg2/pip-egg-     info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
 remote:            Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '12.3'
 remote:            ----------------------------------------
 remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the      logs for full command output.
 remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 remote: 
 remote:  !     Push failed
 remote: Verifying deploy...
 remote: 
 remote: !  Push rejected to heightdata69.
 remote: 
 To https://git.heroku.com/heightdata69.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/heightdata69.git'`
```

Comment: You probably managed to run your project manually. Check your local Python version with `python -V` and specify that version in a `runtime.txt`. Also create a new `requirements.txt` with `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From psycopg documentation, "*The build prerequisites are to be met in order to install psycopg from source code, from a source distribution package, GitHub or from PyPI.*" 
So, for `psycopg2` to be installed using pip, you first need to do some setup found [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#build-prerequisites).

To fix the error you should replace the current version of psycopg2 with `psycopg2-binary==2.8.4` in your `requirements.txt` file without any additional setup.